# JQuery: Help with $("#div")

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just started using JQuery, as such, I'm cleaning up old code of mine to use JQuery throughout.

**Question**: How would I convert the following code to use JQuery?

```
// enable the other link
document.getElementById("asc").setAttribute("href", "#");
document.getElementById("asc").onclick = function() {displayHomeListings("asc")};
document.getElementById("asc").style.textDecoration = "none"

//disable this link
document.getElementById("desc").removeAttribute("href");
document.getElementById("desc").onclick = "";
document.getElementById("desc").style.textDecoration = "underline"
```

Comment: I'm sorry to sound rude, but have you even read the documentation or some starter tutorial?

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#asc').attr('href', '#').click(function() {
    displayHomeListings('asc');
}).css('text-decoration', 'none');
```

You can figure out the other one, although I would generally advise to `addClass` and `removeClass` instead of messing with CSS styles directly. You also wouldn't need to mess with the `href` if you simply `return false;` inside the click function while leaving the `href` in the actual HTML to be something that degrades gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#asc").attr("href", "#")
         .css("text-decoration", "none")
         .click(function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              displayHomeListings("asc");
              return false;
         });

$("#desc").removeAttr("href")
         .css("text-decoration", "underline")
         .unbind("click");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#asc').attr('href', '#').click(function() {
  displayHomeListings('asc');
  return false;
}).css('text-decoration', 'none');

$('#desc').attr('href', '').unbind('click').css('text-decoration', 'underline');
```

Though, assuming the #desc href was set to '#', you don't really need to clear that one.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#asc').attr('href','#');
$('#asc').click(function() {displayHomeListings("asc")});
$('#asc').css('text-decoration','none');

$('#desc').attr('href','');
$('#desc').unbind('click');
$('#desc').css('text-decoration','underline');
```